# LSTM model accuracy checking

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

Is this a good result?
How do you print the model accuracy (in %) from this graph?

[image]

Comment: You need to know what your loss function is

Comment: why is your training data results moving inverse to the test data training results

Comment: @Allan how to do that?

Comment: @GoldenLion any suggestions?

Comment: try to identify the outlier data using standard deviation

Comment: @X002, you need to define beforehand your loss function. See that https://keras.io/api/losses/

Answer (score 2):

That is the graph of the loss curves. It clearly shows that the model is overfitting because the test curve is going up. This is bad. It means that your model will perform badly in data that is not very very similar to the training data.

This graph is not directly related to the accuracy. You cannot know the accuracy by looking at the loss.

Comment: @neo Thanks for the prompt reply. How to fix it?

Comment: Some things you may try are reducing your model capacity (e.g. reducing the embedding size) or applying regularization (e.g. dropout).

Comment: Also, please consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct.